# VBA: Click on Tab from Web page (getelementby?)

Tags: vba, excel

I need to click on the import tab from a web page, I have tried things like:

```
ieApp.document.getElementsByTagName("#tab-import")(1).Click
ieApp.document.getElementsByName("#tab-import").Click
ieApp.document.getElementsById("#tab-import").Click
ieApp.document.all.Item("#tab-import")(1).click
ieApp.document.all.Item("Import").Click
```

The last one runs correctly but nothings happen; this is the linecode that shows the inspect element tool:

```
<li><a href="#tab-import" data-toggle="tab">Import</a></li>
```

Also I have tried to open the web page with the url of the href="#tab-import" but the page starts on the first tab (export)

I don't know what to do, please help.

Comment: Which version of IE you are using?

Comment: Version 11.112.17134.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm giving this solution considering the fact that `href="#tab-import"` appear once in that page you are dealing with and the version of IE is later than 9. The portion of html is too minimum to guess a unique selector.

```
Dim Html As HTMLDocument

Set Html = ieApp.document
Html.querySelector("a[href='#tab-import']").Click
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: Thank you SIM your solution was helpful for me as well.. Thanks a lot.